# button in div to download a video with popup

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button in a div with a link to a video. I'd like to have the prompt popup to download the video. 
I have this code now but it opens a video:

```
<div  class="btn btn-primary-rect " style="text-align: center;" onClick=window.open("<?php echo $lien;?>")>DOWNLOAD THE VIDEO <img src="images/upload.png" class="upload"> </div>
```

How can I do it properly because I need it working in IE and Firefox, Chrome, Safari...

Comment: `DOWNLOAD THE VIDEO <img src="images/upload.png"` - How can a .png file be a video?

Comment: you need an `href` here if anything.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the video link is in the `$lien` php variable, that's just an image for the button

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yeah; I stand corrected ;-) my bad.

Comment: It will always open the video because header is not to force download. The best bet you can do is call an ajax

Comment: @SaadSuri How to do it ? I have no clue...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually coding this in PHP (as suggested in the tags), then you can use a PHP script to stage the file, and then alter the disposition header to tell the browser to treat the file as an attachment for download, something along the lines of:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file-to-download.ext"');
readfile('actual-path-to-file.ext');
```

Doing it this way, rather than linking directly, will allow you control over how the file is handled on the client side.